# Custom tasks and default view in SAS Studio 3.5

Tags: user-interface, sas, sas-studio

I am creating a custom task in SAS Studio 3.5. I want to design a simple user interface so that users can select options and input parameters.

When SAS Studio opens, there is a code and log window, when the task is opened there are then a few extra tabs at the top.

I would like to know if 
A) the log and code window can be deselected by default
B) if, when the task is opened, it displays *only* the user interface (form) to fill in.

I basically want as few things for the user to click on as possible.

Comment: To run the macros you need SAS installed. One option is to use SAS EG for these users with a defined prompt panel and another is to develop custom tasks for SAS Studio. I think SAS Studio may be easier to new users to pick up and less intimidating.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deliver a modern UI is to use HTML5.  This is waay easier than using SAS/AF, more supportable (plenty of web resource available in the market), scalable, requires no client install (virtually all clients have browsers!), and you can make use of the '000s of free libraries available (jQuery, Boostrap, HandsOnTable etc).

I have written a simple guide for building web applications with SAS:

http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas.html

Comment: Linking my answer to the original question:  http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41680465/1